# Pardot API to retrieve all records from Prospect table

Tags: talend, pardot

I'm using Talend to issue API call to Pardot and retrieve records from Prospect table.
This gives me just 200 records. 
Can anyone suggest a way to retrieve all the records available in this table.

Or how to loop over and retrieve records in chunks of 200 and terminate when the records retrieved is zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can only retrieve 200 records at a time. If you want to retrieve all the records, you have to loop it using the offset parameter. Here the offset increases by 200 each time i.e. when you use offset=0 it will retrieve first 200 records and then increase the offset by 200 (offset=200) to retrieve the next 200 records. Here is how I retrieved all the records into a csv file in Python.

```
i=0
final_data = pd.DataFrame() #Initialize an empty dataframe
url = "https://pi.pardot.com/api/Prospect/version/4/do/query? user_key=&api_key=&output=bulk&format=json&sort_by=&src=&offset="+str(i)
while requests.get(url).json()['result'] is not None:
  url = "https://pi.pardot.com/api/Prospect/version/4/do/query? user_key=&api_key=&output=bulk&format=json&sort_by=&src=&offset="+str(i)
  data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(requests.get(url).json()['result']['prospect'])
  final_data=data.append(final_data)
  i=i+200
final_data.to_csv('complete_data.csv',index=False)
```

I used the condition `requests.get(url).json()['result'] is not None` because I do not have any idea regarding the number of offsets present. So I am checking every time if records are present in that offset. This might take too long in the case you have several thousands of offsets. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

## Providing a modified and working solution

I have avoided using "Offset" parameter as it is suggested not to use it for bulk data pull.

```
"""defining a function for getting an api key using credentials for Pardot user"""

def api_key_gen():
    import requests
    import json

    url = "https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3%20HTTP/1.1"
    
    querystring = {"email":"","password":"","user_key":"","format":"json"}
    
    headers = {
        'Connection': "keep-alive",
        'cache-control': "no-cache"
        }
    
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    
#    print(json.loads(response.text)['api_key'])
    return (json.loads(response.text)['api_key'])
```

#### Using these two functions to fetch data.

1. First function fetches data using between two dates.
2. Second function is used if there are large number of records stored in a single second.

```
def fetchFromDate(api_key, max_date, target_date):
    url = "https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/3/do/query? user_key=&api_key="+str(api_key)+"&output=bulk&created_after="+str(max_date)+"&created_before="+str(target_date)+"&format=json"
    result = json.loads((requests.request("GET", url)).text)['result']['prospect']
    data = pd.DataFrame(result)
    return data

def fetchFromId(api_key, max_id):
    url = "https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/3/do/query? user_key=&api_key="+str(api_key)+"&output=bulk&id_greater_than="+str(max_id)+"&format=json"
    result = json.loads((requests.request("GET", url)).text)['result']['prospect']
    data = pd.DataFrame(result)
    return data
```

Using below code to fetch data from pardot api for one month to keep size of data small.Also whenever api key gets expired,a new key api key is fetched and used in the URL.Dates are used to compare with each other in order to fetch data for desired period only.I have tried to keep the whole process Dynamic except for the dates parameters.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

"""using a start date and target date to fetch data for a particular time span"""

max_date = '2014-02-03 08:02:57'
target_date = datetime.strptime('2014-06-30 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


final_data = pd.DataFrame() #Initialize an empty dataframe
api_key = api_key_gen()
last_maxDate = max_date
last_maxId = '' #get the id of first record for desired year and fill here
url = "https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/3/do/query? user_key=&api_key="+str(api_key)+"&output=bulk&created_after="+str(max_date)+"&created_before="+str(target_date)+"&format=json"
print("Start Time : ",datetime.now())
i =1
while json.loads((requests.request("GET", url)).text)['result'] is not None:
#    max_date = datetime.strptime(str(max_date),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')-timedelta(seconds=1)
    last_maxDate = datetime.strptime(str(last_maxDate),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    api_key = api_key_gen()
    data = fetchFromDate(api_key, max_date, target_date)
    if len(data) < 200:
        final_data=data.append(final_data,ignore_index=True)
        break
    else:
        max_id = max(data['id'])
        max_date = max(data['created_at'])
        max_date = datetime.strptime(str(max_date),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')-timedelta(seconds=1)
#        print(type(max_date),type(last_maxDate))
        if bool(max_date == last_maxDate) & bool(int(max_id) == int(last_maxId)):
            print("Running through Id's")
            api_key = api_key_gen()
            data = fetchFromId(api_key, max_id)
#            final_data=data.append(final_data,ignore_index=True)
            max_id = max(data['id'])
            max_date = max(data['created_at'])
        final_data=data.append(final_data,ignore_index=True)
        last_maxDate = max_date
        last_maxId = max_id
        print("Running Loop :",i,max_date,max_id)
        i += 1

print(max(data['created_at']))
print(max(data['id']))
final_data.to_csv('file.csv',index=False)
print("End Time : ",datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the Pardot API key expires after every 60 minutes. So it is better to use [PyPardot4](https://github.com/mneedham91/PyPardot4/blob/master/README.md) in python which can use a new API key whenever the current key expires.

You can use the following code.

```
from pypardot.client import PardotAPI
import requests
import pandas as pd
p = PardotAPI(
    email='',
    password='',
    user_key='')
p.authenticate()    
i=0
final_data = pd.DataFrame()
while i <=p.prospects.query()['total_results'] -1: 
  print(i)
  data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(p.prospects.query(format='json',sort_by='id',offset=i)['prospect'])
  final_data=data.append(final_data,sort=True)
  i=i+200
final_data.to_csv('complete_data.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are good for looping. If you only need a limited amount of fields, look into the mobile response format, it doesn't have the 200 record limit. It only supports a couple of predefined fields however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Export API that works for the Prospect table. This can give a year's data. So logically create each year query.